# Event's scheduling algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, scheduling

I've got a list of events each having a duration.
I'm looking to write an algorithm to schedule these events for a day. From 9AM to 12PM and then from 1PM to no earlier than 4PM and no later than 5PM.

I'm not sure what will be a good approach to solving this.
Since there could be several possible solutions, my first thought is to test random combinations for correctness.

I'd like to know if there's a more deterministic way of solving this.
Thanks ;)

**EDIT**

@svs
The timing for events is in minutes and no events should overlap.
Also there's no need for pauses between events except for a lunch break from 12PM to 1PM.

Comment: What are your rules?  If you have none, just sequentially fill the schedule as long as it fits..

Comment: This is basically a knapsack problem with 2 knapsacks. There is no known polynomial solution for it, although we know a pseudo-polynomial one for integer weights.

Comment: `I've got a list of events each having a duration.` what is the resolution of the duration - seconds, minutes, hours? The event should not overlap? Should there be pauses between the event? Any restrictions at all? Are trying to minimize the remaining time for those two time windows?

Comment: It would help if you post some example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ergonaut that would not work. if it doesn't fit, would I then have to backtrack and try a different ordering?

Comment: you could sort them and add the "largest that will fit", rinse and repeat.

Comment: @ergonaut please elaborate on what you mean by "rinse and repeat"

Comment: Give input and output examples, how could anyone know what you want without that?

Comment: Assuming it's impossible to schedule all of them, what measure are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 yeah, I should do that. But ergonaut's example is spot on. I'll put up something similar in an edit just for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Since you basically have two equal time-slot buckets, you can essentially schedule them all in sequence regardless of order, and assuming there is a solution, look for how you can even them out.  Start with buckets A and B.

Put the largest event e1 in bucket A.
Then put the next largest event e2 in bucket B.
Put the largest event in bucket B that is at most e1-e2 minutes long.  Keep adding to bucket B until your bucket B has no more than A's total minutes.

Then repeat the above, (switching A for B).

Keep repeating the above until you are complete your events.

This will only work because you each bucket has the same length, 180 minutes.

Actually since you have this 4-5pm rule, any extra events will be left over at the end.  They will all go in one bucket, and this will be the afternoon bucket.  If for some reason you have an event that is > 180 minutes, then that will book the afternoon.  Then if you fit as many as you can in the morning (from largest to smallest), then the rest would go in the afternoon.

Comment: @G.Bach He explained what 4:89 means at the top. Event 4 is 89 minutes long.

Comment: Say you have two time windows of 100 and 80 minutes, and jobs [1:50, 2:50, 3:80], then this algorithm will fail, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Okay I missed this point.  I thought you have unlimited days like the dentist. You want this all to fit in a single day.. like a conference!